# CSS vertical-align: middle not working on nav bar with text to the left and login link to the right

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have a page with a header, followed by a (menu/tool) bar underneath, which is supposed to carry two elements: a text to the left (big font) and a login link (smaller text). The right hand link is supposed the be centered vertically.

The following resource seemed to be exactly what I need:

http://www.css4you.de/Texteigenschaften/vertical-align.html

and

http://www.css4you.de/example/vertical-align.html

Here's my HTML:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid purple;">
  <h1 style="border: 1px solid red; display: inline;">Textext</h1>
  <span id="logindisplay" style="border: 1px solid lime; float: right; vertical-align: middle;"><a href="/admin/login.xhtml">Log In</a></span>
</div>
```

The CSS ID selector for logindisplay doesn't exist. h1 is just

```
h1
{
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

I basically did everything as in the resource above, but it doesn't work - neither on IE9 nor on FF. Here's what I get:

[image: Browser appearance]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

**Note**: Workarounds/hacks aren't desired. (One would be to set padding-top: on the span...)

Comment: The float:right negates the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using float:right negates the vertical-align as you found. Mark's suggestion doesn't work with position:relative on the div? In which case, line-height seems like the easiest way.

Comment: Well, yes and no. First of all I wasn't looking for workarounds. Second line-height is no better than the padding-top workaround I came up with. I've implemented a third variant as HTML table. I'll let the customer decide. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#logindisplay { line-height: 18pt; }
```

...and get rid of your vertical-align property.

`vertical-align` doesn't work in the way you thinkit does, it seems. Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ for a good explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 1):

make your outer div be `display: table-cell`, or give it a `line-height` of appropriate size.

vertical-align is one of the stupidest bits of CSS, and rarely works as you'd expect without having to hack up containing elements: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Setting outer to display: table-cell doesn't work. This is nasty stuff.

Comment: The problem is the mandatory `float: right` which really deletes `align-vertical`. So the only things working are `line-height` or `padding-top` hacks. I'll probably use a table the get the alignments right.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be putting position relative on the parent div and then absolute position the span like this:

```
#logindisplay {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UmrMp/)

Comment: This works, too. I missed the parent's `position: relative` part.